# sumif in vba on array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

`enter code here`i try to sum all positive value in my array but every time object not found or parameter misssing error seen.

```
Option Explicit

Sub trail2()
    With ThisWorkbook
        Dim arr1 As New ArrayList
        arr1.Add 20
        arr1.Add -15
        arr1.Add 20.77
        msgbox  Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(arr1, ">0")
    end with
end sub
```

error = object not found or parameter misssing error seen

i also try on range but thats also not working

```
Option Explicit
Sub trail2()
dim rr as variant
dim i as variant
 With ThisWorkbook
 rr = Range(.Sheets("data").Cells(2, 5), .Sheets("data").Cells(4, 5))
 msgbox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rr, ">0")
end with
end sub
```

same data as per array but error seen.
error = object required
i don't want that sheet data so i need only array for sumif.
how to slove it ?

Comment: The first parameter of `CountIf` must be a `Range`, so that approach won't work. Use a loop.

Comment: `msgbox = ....` ----> `MsgBox ...`. No `=`.

Comment: "I also try on range": you actually didn't. `rr` is a `Variant` array, not a `Range`.

Comment: You need Set rr = Range(.Sheets("data").Cells(2, 5), .Sheets("data").Cells(4, 5))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning a range to a variable, you need to use `Set`

You should also use the worksheet your range is on to avoid it pulling from an active sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub trial2()

Dim rr As Range

Dim i As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        Set rr = .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(4, 5))
        MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rr, ">0")
    End With
End Sub
```